# Docker run time environment variable is not available

Tags: docker, runtime, docker-run

I have the need to pass a variable at runtime when the docker run command is run and the same is to be read inside the container.

This is the docker run command that i use

```
docker run  -it -e "URL=test" test bash
```

But the variable URL is not available inside the container. My Dockerfile as below

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "test"
RUN echo "The url is " $URL >> /out.log
```

Inside the container, out.log shows only the following ouput

> The url is

What am i missing?

Comment: `RUN` inside a Dockerfile is used at "build" time, not when you `docker run` new containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this variable available during build time, use `--build-arg` - [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

If you need this variable available during run (container) time, then use an environment variable and define an `ENTRYPOINT` script that does whatever it needs using this variable.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I define an ENV variable at build time like ENV a 1. But when I run the image, this a is not present. What am I doing wrong?